# SSL Certificate Does Not Work With Curl "unable to get local issuer certificate"

Tags: curl, https, server, openssl, certificate

My web server is set up to force HTTPS, as in the future I'm working on projects that involve transfer of user data so encryption will be needed. But for now I'm just testing things out. Unfortunately I've got an issue I can't seem to figure out no matter what I try!

I'm using a custom server engine (written in C for maximum speed of course!), the SSL is implemented using openssl installed on the latest Ubuntu Server. I can provide some code if that's relevant, but the thing is... It works 100% perfectly in Chrome, Edge, and Firefox, tested on everything from PC, Mac, Android, even my old iPhone. All have no issues negotiating to TLS 1.2 AES.

But there are two things in particular that don't work. One, CURL, which seems to fail with this obscure SSL-related error "(60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate", and oddly, my Smart TV, LG B8 OLED, which has a certificate error as well and suggests double-checking the date/time settings, which are correct.

Here's the web address if anyone wants to test: https://forestfire.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message is the same as the `X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY` error documented here:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/X509_STORE_CTX_get_error.html

> the issuer certificate could not be found: this occurs if the issuer
>   certificate of an untrusted certificate cannot be found.

Typically when you configure your server you need to set up the server's own certificate plus any required intermediate certificates in the certificate chain (these are the "untrusted" certificates referred to above). On the client side you need the list of trusted CA certificates.

You could get this error if your list of intermediate certificates in the certificate chain is missing or incorrect in some way, or if the client does not have the CA for the top of the "untrusted" chain in its trust store.

You can get different behaviour between different clients if those clients have different certificates in their trust store. For example the browsers may have some of the intermediate certificates cached and therefore can complete the chain even though the server does not present them.

Comment: Okay, so I purchased my cert from COMODO through NameCheap, and when I download it, I get a ZIP file with three files, a `.crt` file, a `.p7b` file, and a `.ca-bundle` file. OpenSSL (or at least the way I have in configured at the moment) wanted a .crt file, so I just used that.

What I'm getting from this is that there needs to be some kind of chain of certificates? So should I use the `.ca-bundle` file instead and rename it to .crt? It looked like it was multiple certificates inside, looking at it in a text editor.

Comment: Okay, I just tried taking the chain of certificates from the ca-bundle and appending them to the end of the crt file. The server starts right up and doesn't seem to error on that certificate file, however the problem remains, same error with curl and with the Smart TV.

Comment: Eureka! Figured it out now, combining the `crt` and the `ca-bundle` was the correct approach, however that wasn't working, because I was using the `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file` function instead of the `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file` function. Using the latter, openssl loaded all the certificates in the chain, and then it worked with both curl and the Smart TV!